# Cannot edit column type and set it as URL

Tags: 2013, column

I'm using SharePoint 2013. I have a list with custom columns. One column is text type, and I want to set it as URL type. In SharePoint Designer, I can change the type, but I can't choose "URL" type.

I tried in powershell, doesn't work too. According to [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/add-and-modify-the-existing-site-column-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/) site.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://serverName/"
$web = $site.RootWeb 
$field=$web.Fields["Custom Site Column"]
$field.Type= "URL"
$field.Update($true)
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

I also tried :

```
$field.Type= [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::URL
```

Instead of :

```
$field.Type= "URL"
```

But when I did the `Update($true)` or `Update()`. Answer an error like : you cannot use this type.
I don't want to delete the list and create it again, because there is lots of aspx page inside and else.

Any ideas to force the column type to be URL ?

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: Update question

Comment: Well, If I can't see the choice in my browser, or in SPD, and cannot do it in powershell .. I guess it's impossible =/

Comment: You can force a change by updating the "XML" attribute of the field with powershell, but it would most likely break it

Comment: Yes, doing something like : `<Field Type="URL" Format="Hyperlink"` I think it's better to create it again, don't you think too ?

Comment: Absolutely, because the URL field stores at least two different values internally (separated with ;# or similar) so it would be hard for you to convert it

Comment: Ok. I'm going to work on this list again. Just another little question, do you have bookmarked something to set view level permission ? as its not a OOTB feature. I use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433486/How-to-set-view-level-permissions-out-of-the-box-i). But just wanted to know if you have a perfect link close to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Sharepoint Manager 2013. First test with sample column then apply to your column.

You can download sharepoint manager from:

http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: Really nice soft, even if it shows lots of error. So I'm able to see my column type, set it as URL, but when I save, I still have an error.

Comment: So its won't let you change the column it any way. You should try to create a new column and try to copy the data to that column.

Comment: What is the error you getting?

Comment: A Debugging error. When I try changing the XML Schema, tells me that Value not accepted. So I think It's impossible. would be better to create it again, even if create a new column is simple. I don't need another column.

Comment: But What If I delete my current column, and create a new one with good type ? The column order would be the same ? Nothing to deal with column ID ? Well, I'm gonna try.

Comment: You can set your column order as your wish from modify view

Comment: I've just a last little question. Some item in my URL type column, need to not be a link. Is that possible to modify the item properties to disable the link ? or any URL that wouldn't do anything ?

Comment: How do you know you need to disable the field?

Comment: I use a PS script to create list and view. If other list view (with defined with Client's name) doesn't exist, I Create the item Client, but I dont' want to be a link, because there is nothing behind.

Comment: You can set allow null or empty values in the column definition. So for that case you can set it empty.

Comment: Yes, but I need to write the Client's name. So it won't be empty. (I'm in the chat)

Comment: I don't think this would be possible as you have to provide the URL as it is a URL field.

Comment: This morning I want to do impossible things ! I will search to put an URL that doesn't do anything.